# typo3 issue with ssl in backend - mixed content

Tags: nginx, typo3, lets-encrypt, typo3-8.x

I use typo3 8.7. It's a server with nginx and let's encrypt.

All works fine but saving content elements returns an error:

[image]

Certificate is fine:

[image]

What could be the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it some static url somewhere in the code or database?

Comment: can't remember to old question^^